# Weird characters being added to my link

Tags: links

I created a simple image link that's linking to a page within my Wordpress website and for some reason weird characters are being appended to in which is not allowing the user to get the the page destination.  Please help!

This is the website: http://bit.ly/1ko2xwM its the link under "click here to preview". I'm just doing a simple anchor tag.

```
<a id="book-preview" href="/excerpt-want-get-married/‎"> <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/Book-Preview-CTA.png" alt="Look Inside Book"></a>
```

Comment: What software are you using to edit the code?

Comment: I'm editing the code in Dreamweaver as I usually do.

Comment: Interesting. Disable your plugins, especially (my guess) any that alter page content via Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this by just retyping the anchor code.